# When is the extension defined by an Eisenstein polynomial galoisian or abelian or cyclic ?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, $K$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $\mathfrak{o}$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p}$ the unique maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$, $k=\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ the residue field, and $q=\operatorname{Card} k$.

Recall that a polynomial $\varphi=T^n+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1T+c_0$ ($n>0$) in $K[T]$ is said to be **Eisenstein** if  $c_i\in\mathfrak{p}$ for $i\in[0,n[$ and if $c_0\notin\mathfrak{p}^2$.

**Question.** When is the extension $L_\varphi$ defined by $\varphi$ galoisian (resp. abelian, resp. cyclic) over $K$ ?

**Background.**  Every Eisenstein polymonial $\varphi$ is irreducible, the extension $L_\varphi=K[T]/\varphi K[T]$ is totally ramified over $K$, and every root of $\varphi$ in $L_\varphi$ is a uniformiser of $L_\varphi$.  There is a converse.

If the degree $n$ of $\varphi$ is prime to $p$, then the extension $L_\varphi|K$ is tamely ramified and can be defined by the polynomial $T^n-\pi$ for some uniformiser $\pi$ of $K$.  Thus $L_\varphi|K$ is galoisian if and only if $n|q-1$, and, when such is the case, $L_\varphi|K$ is actually cyclic.

**Real question**.  Is there a similar criterion, in case $n=p^m$ is a power of $p$, for deciding if  $L_\varphi|K$ is galoisian (resp. abelian, resp. cyclic) ?

Comment: Do you mean [0,n-1]?

Comment: Yes.  $[0,n[=[0,n-1]$, as intervals in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: (For those who don't know: in Europe one excludes the endpoint of an interval not by "(" or ")" but by inverting the bracket, e.g. ]a,b[ = (a,b).  One could argue that this is more logical than the "American" notation, although -- as usual when someone points out a more logical alternative to your current practice? -- I take the point but haven't actually changed over.)

Comment: For some reason, all of my professors are very against including 0 in the natural numbers.

Comment: Definition.  $\mathbb{N}$ is the free monoid on one generator, namely 1.  Corollary. $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Pete: I thought that was more common amongst, say, French texts than UKian ones, but am drawing on a very limited sample...

Comment: @Pete: I'm from Spain, and we use (a,b) rather than ]a,b[. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Chandan, my understanding is that 0 tends to be in N in several European countries, but not in America.  I have been told to use the notation Z_{\ge 0} to avoid ambiguity.  (Personally I agree with you, but for a slightly different reason - the non-negative integers are precisely the set of cardinalities of finite sets.)

Comment: @Chandan: And what part of the `$SACRED_BOOK` says that one should not define $\mathbb N$ as the free semigroup on one generator? :)

Comment: I learn just now that people in America don'tuse ]a,b[ or do not include 0 in the naturals. I knew there was not complete agreement on these practices, but I didn't think it was a regional difference (especially the 0).

Comment: @YC, AGR: Sorry, I didn't mean to speak for all of Europe.  I think it is very standard in France, and I know it is also used (sometimes) in the Netherlands.  I don't know how it goes country by country.  @AF: Yes, some Americans most certainly do assert $0 \in \mathbb{N}$: I do, for instance.  Over here, it seems to depend upon whether you are an algebraist (so you want to include the identity element of the monoid) or an analyst (so you can take reciprocals without having to divide by zero).  Of course this is just a rough rule of thumb...

Comment: The notation $(a,b)$  is used for the ordered pair, for the open interval, and for the gcd. I prefer to use $(a,b)$ , $]a,b[$, and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$. If you want to exclude 0  from $\mathbb{N}$, use $\mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: More specifically, using parentheses for open intervals is an english North American thing. In french school in Quebec, one is taught inverted square brackets. This indicates that it might very well be mostly a french (i.e. francophone) thing. Any Sénégalese mathematicians around these parts? We didn't have a notation for natural numbers and integers in high school, so I can't speak to that, but I avoid $\mathbf{N}$ in favour of $\mathbf{Z}_{\geq0}$ (just as I avoid $\subset$ and use $\subseteq$).

Comment: btw I say "more specifically" with respect to Pete's assertion that it is an "American" thing. Despite appearances, I'm not claiming that it is strictly an english North American thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where the ground field $K$ is $\mathbb{Q}_p$, some old work of Lbekkouri has recently been published [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-009-0026-3). In particular, for that case, i.e. for finite totally wildly ramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, normality is equivalent to cyclicity. Furthermore:

When $n=p$, this was answered by Ore in the 30's:
the extension is normal if and only if $p^2|c_j$ for $1\leq j\leq p-2$ and $p^2|(c_0+c_{p-1})$.

When $n=p^2$, Lbekkouri gives a list of necessary and sufficent congruence conditions on the coefficients $c_j$.

More generally for $n=p^m$, he gives some necessary conditions but since the methods require detailed computations with the ramification filtration, it seems unlikely that one could extend the sufficient conditions much beyond the $p^2$ case.

Comment: Many thanks, dke.  Nice to know that the degree-p case was considered by Ore in the 30s, and that the degree-p^2 case was settled only last year.  So it appears that the general case is an open problem.

Comment: [Updated link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-009-0026-3) for the Lbekkouri article (the one in the answer is now broken).

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have come across [an early paper](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SDPP_1967-1968__9_1_A6_0) of Jean-Marc Fontaine --- apparently his first paper --- in which he treats a special case of the problem: Proposition 3 gives a criterion for the (totally ramified) extension defined by an Eisenstein polynomial of $p$-power degree to be galoisian *with a unique ramification break* ($>0$).

Comment: The link in your answer is broken.

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/item/SDPP_1967-1968__9_1_A6_0/

Comment: I'll put bibliographic information here in case the link does not work for someone: Extensions finies galoisiennes des corps valués complets à valuation discrète
Fontaine, Séminaire Delange-Pisot-Poitou. Théorie des nombres, Volume 9 (1967-1968) no. 1, Talk no. 6, 21 pages.